# Create bundled version of npm kafka-node

Tags: javascript, npm, apache-kafka, bundle

I'm very new to js-module-systems-and-building-libraries. I'm trying to figure out if its possible to convert npm kafka-node libraries which I believe are bundled in Universal Module Definition format into the bundled version of the library.  ie. one minified js file that can be loaded into the browser.  If someone could point me to away that I can do this by using existing npm kafka-node libraries that would be very helpful.

Comment: Ok so it turns out I was just a newbie here.  I didn't realize that kafka-node can only be used on server side that is why there is no browser distribution file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after I figured out that I was trying to use a server-side package in the client I found https://docs.confluent.io/current/kafka-rest/api.html#id3 which was a great fit for allowing client side consuming of kafka.